# Add Javascript and HTML form entries to database

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database, schedule

How can I add this javascript/html form to the database? I know only how to connect html/php with SQL...

here is the code that will allow the user to pick up the dates but its connected with javascript .. I need a way to save it into the database ..

HTML

```
<div id="hourForm">
    <div id="Sunday" class="day"></div>
    <div id="Monday" class="day"></div>
    <div id="Tuesday" class="day"></div>
    <div id="Wednesday" class="day"></div>
    <div id="Thursday" class="day"></div>
    <div id="Friday" class="day"></div>
    <div id="Saturday" class="day"></div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('.day').each(function() {
    var day = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).append('<div id="label">' + day + ': </div>');
    $(this).append('<select name="' + day + 'FromH" class="hour from"></select>');
    $(this).append('<select name="' + day + 'FromM" class="min from"></select>');
    $(this).append('<select name="' + day + 'FromAP" class="ampm from"></select>');
    $(this).append(' to <select name="' + day + 'ToH" class="hour to"></select>');
    $(this).append('<select name="' + day + 'ToM" class="min to"></select>');
    $(this).append('<select name="' + day + 'ToAP" class="ampm to"></select>');
    $(this).append(' <input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed" class="closed"><span>Closed</span>');

});

$('.hour').each(function() {
    for (var h = 1; h < 13; h++) {
        $(this).append('<option value="' + h + '">' + h + '</option>');
    }

    $(this).filter('.from').val('9');
    $(this).filter('.to').val('5');
});

$('.min').each(function() {
    var min = [':00', ':15', ':30', ':45'];
    for (var m = 0; m < min.length; m++) {
        $(this).append('<option value="' + min[m] + '">' + min[m] + '</option>');
    }

    $(this).val(':00');
});

$('.ampm').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<option value="AM">AM</option>');
    $(this).append('<option value="PM">PM</option>');

    $(this).filter('.from').val('AM');
    $(this).filter('.to').val('PM');
});

$('input').change( function() { 
    if($(this).filter(':checked').val() == "closed") {
        $(this).siblings('select').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('select').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#Saturday .closed, #Sunday .closed').val(["closed"]).siblings('select').attr('disabled', true);
```

please give me a hint or a tutorial if you can't help..

Comment: If you know how to make a php page connect to sql, you can probably look up a "javascript ajax post" tutorial and get there.  You have the php page which writes to the DB already?

Comment: Where did you get the date picker code from?  There should be examples.  If not, use a different date picker.  Most you can still use form submits, so you don't necessarily need to use ajax to post the data.

Comment: @CharlieWynn Yes... my case is too complicated I am doing an html form a database using php and then google map imports the values on the map as markers. Now I want the form to stores the opening times to show if a location is open or closed.. can you help me? here or on google+ or Facebook ? I don't have enough time to submit my school project

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to learn how to use AJAX, this will allow you to send and receive data from the database, usually you'll have some PHP which will display JSON and your AJAX will request this from the PHP page.

http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Your AJAX will look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "test.php",
    data: { param1 : "Bob", param2 : "Larry" },
    dataType: "script"
});
```

This will call your PHP file "test" and pass in parameters param1 and param2

Comment: my case is too complicated I am doing an html form a database using php and then google map imports the values on the map as markers. Now I want the form to stores the opening times to show if a location is open or closed.. can you help me? here or on google+ or Facebook ? I don't have enough time to submit my school project

Comment: This can all be done through AJAX, I used AJAX to get data from Google Maps before.

Comment: Jessica how can I get in touch with you?

Comment: my Facebook is : Nadim Al Ayaseh
my email is : n4d@live.com

Comment: I don't give help outside of here sorry :/

Comment: ok Jessica how can I store opening hours and days into SQL what is the SQL code and the html attributes types?

Comment: You want to use the DateTime data type, as for the HTML, it's the same way as you would normally do it, give the element a name, pass it to the server code and do a SQL Insert with the date passed in

Comment: How is that a question?

Comment: but everytime has a differnet working times how can I do everytime with its  attributes should it be like 21 culomns !!!?

Comment: No, you should use reference tables, create a new table and give it an ID which is linked to the main table, this will allow you to have as many entries for 1 record, research of foreign / reference tables